# Objects in JAVA

Tags: java

```
Project sample = new Project();
```

This means creating a variable sample of type project, creating an object and assigning it to variable.

What does below code mean

```
 Project sample = new Project() {

  private void Test(){

   }

}
```

Test is a method, What this code means, How do Test() can be invoked ?

Thanks

Comment: search in google for something called annonymous class. In this class your Test class will not be called since its private

Comment: @Jayamohan:Thanks.When should I use this type of objects ?

Comment: This is not type of object. This construction is used typically for implemeting interfaces.

Comment: @Vash: why not object? This is an object.

Comment: The use of anonymous class in my view comes only in following scenarios
Only one Instance required, Used right away when defined, Very Short body 

Many other casses are there other than these. Mr. Google should answer you the remaining.

Comment: @Andremoniy, It is a object. But without any specific "type of object" is normal object. In fact Java will crate a private class for such anonymous .

Comment: @Vash: what do you mean by "specific type of object"?

Comment: The quote was from user ram, ask him or read the comments one more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to other answers. This kind of anonymous classes are very useful when you're implementing `interface` or extending `abstract` class. For instance:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void doStuff();
}
```

And here is your implementation:

```
MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterface() {

    public void doStuff() {
        //here is your implementation
    }

    public void doAnotherStuff() {
        //Note that this method is public, but
        //you're still not able to call it from outside of this class
        //because it's not part of MyInterface's contract
    }
};
```

This line will give you an error:

```
myInterface.doAnotherStuff(); //WTF? I don't know about this method of MyInterface
```

Comment: @Dmittry Zaitsev:Can you explain why I can n't call second method outside of  class in detail.

Comment: @ram because it is not part of parent class contract. Look, in my example you have reference to `MyInterface`, so you can call only methods declared in `MyInterface` (even if your actual class is differ from it). Since `doAnotherStuff` is not declared in `MyInterface` you can't call it.

Comment: @ram honestly, I don't think that this answer is best one. I just provide an another look at your problem.

Answer (score 5):

This:

1. creates an anonymous subclass of `Project`;
2. within that class, creates a new method called `Test()` (in other circumstances this could be an override, but here it can't be);
3. creates an instance of this subclass;
4. assigns the instance reference to `sample`.

`Test()` being `private`, the only way to call it is from another method of the anonymous subclass. Since you have no other methods, there's no way to call `Test()`.

Comment: You edit so fast, than i can not comment the missing items ;-). +1

Comment: I'm agree with everything, except last statement. "Test()" method can be theoretically invoked; please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Project sample = new Project() {

  private void Test(){

   }

}
```

Simply creates an anonymous class that extends Project which returns and the `new` returns the anonymous object.
The `Test` method is either newly defined instance method or (overridden if `Project` has a `Test` method).

Comment: :When should I use this type of anonymoys objects ? How do I invoke Test()

Comment: It is private.. you can't, unless you have a public method in Project, that calls Test()

Comment: As someone said already.. google anonymous classes. (And I have to go out now.. sorry)

Comment: @ram It is a useful way of quickly invoking an abstract class, or making an already existing class and overriding a method without writing a whole new class declaration. It is most commonly used when you'll be invoking several in one class, or where the new class will only have a single use.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have presented is an example of [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm).

As you have declared in it a private method you can access to it only from inside of that class.

This type of construction is generally used, for locally changes in class behavior. Typically it is used to implement an simple interface. So we are able to delegate some operations in it.